# Calling ESP32 web server REST API from mobile browser

Tags: javascript, cors, esp32

I built an Arduino project on an ESP32 device with an array of NeoPixel LEDs: [Glowing Pumpkin](https://github.com/johnwargo/glowing-pumpkin-xiao-bff). It randomly displays colors and lightning flashes and is intended to reside inside a carved pumpkin.

I'm [extending the project with a web server](https://github.com/johnwargo/glowing-pumpkin-xiao-bff-server) running on one of the ESP32 cores (mostly just because I wanted to learn how to run code on multiple cores in an Arduino project).

The REST API works great with the desktop browser with CORS enabled, but due to security restrictions in Chrome when connecting to an endpoint using HTTP, I had to enable Insecure Content in Site settings for the web app that interacts with the ESP32 device: ([Pumpkin Controller](https://pumpkin-controller.netlify.app/)).

```js
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
const fetchOptions = { mode: "cors", headers };

async function execCmd(cmdStr) {

  var ipAddress = localStorage.getItem(hostAddressKey);
  if (ipAddress == null || ipAddress == "") {
    console.error('Missing IP Address');    
    return;
  }

  let theURL = `http://${ipAddress}/${cmdStr}`;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(theURL, fetchOptions);
    response.json()
      .then(json => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          Swal.fire({
            text: 'Successfully executed command',
            toast: true,
            timer: 1500,
            position: 'top',
            icon: successIcon
          });
        } else {
          console.log(`HTTP error: ${response.status}`);
        }
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.dir(err);
  }
}
```

With Insecure Content enabled for the site in Chrome, I get a warning in the console, but it still works:

```
Click: btnRandom
index.js:79 Executing: http://192.168.86.230/random
index.js:82 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://pumpkin-controller.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://192.168.86.230/random'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
execCmd @ index.js:82
(anonymous) @ index.js:48
```

I ultimately want to access the Pumpkin Controller using a mobile device, but Chrome on Android doesn't allow users to enable Insecure content in Site Settings, so I'm dead in the water here.

Is there another way I can connect to the ESP32 device's REST API via HTTP in a browser app? Is there an HTTP library that available that goes around the Chrome restrictions?

As I coded the web app, Copilot recommended code that made an XHR request instead of using `fetch` - is that because I can do what I want to do using XHR instead of `fetch`?

I know I could deploy a SSL certificate to the ESP32 device and get around this, but I don't want to have to do that as it's complicated.

I know I could do this from a Flutter app for Android and iOS (as I've done that before), but I've not tested it from a Flutter browser app.

**Update**

Accessing the server from a mobile device immediately fails with the following error:

```
Click: btnOff
index.js:79 Executing: http://192.168.86.230/off
index.js:82 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://pumpkin-controller.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://192.168.86.230/off'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
execCmd @ index.js:82
(anonymous) @ index.js:42
index.js:99 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at execCmd (https://pumpkin-controller.netlify.app/index.js:82:28)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://pumpkin-controller.netlify.app/index.js:42:3)
index.js:100 Failed to fetch
```

Comment: First, you should remove `headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');` in the client code. These are response headers, not request headers. Can you clarify your actual problem with CORS? I don't really understand why you mix HTTPS with HTTP.

Comment: The server (ESP32 device) serves over HTTP, there's no SSL cert on it. The web app serves from https://pumpkin-controller.netlify.app/ which is SSL/TLS secured. The problem is that you can't get data back from the server on a mobile browser (in this case Chrome on Android). On the desktop browser you can enable insecure content and it works (just gives a warning as shown in my question). On mobile browser it doesn't work at all, fails immediately on the connection.

Comment: Serve everything with HTTP or add a proxy for the HTTP calls.

Comment: I already know that serving everything over HTTP solves this problem, but that's not an option I want to pursue. I want to host this web app publicly and Netlify forces an SSL connection unless I setup a custom domain. I don't want a custom domain for this. Setting up a proxy is also challenging because the device is a wi-fi device running on my home network and is not visible outside of my network. I don't want to run a node server on my home network for this. My specific ask is if there's an HTTP library I can use in my app to get around this or am I going to have to use a native mobile app?

Comment: There is no way to solve this problem in the client code. Browsers won't allow it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I built a Flutter app for it.